# Swift Execution Order ViewController UIKit

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to swift and want to use the data from an api in form of a json file. I'm using the TableViewController but the execution order in it seems to be jumping around between the functions and not executing them fully. To see in which order the execution is happening I inserted some print statements.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var Info = Array<String>()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

            parse() { result in
                print("parse")
                if result != nil {
                    self.Info = result!
                    tableView.reloadData()
                }
                else {return}
            }

        print("viewDidLoad")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("numberOfRows")
        //
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("cellForRowAt")
        //
    }



}
```

The result of executing it is:

**viewDidLoad
numberOfRows
numberOfRows
parse**

So my Question would be:

How do i get the jsonParse completionHandler to execute before numberofRows and why is cellForRowAt not executing ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show us your `parse` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't because its the completion handler you are calling. But you can again call the tableview numberOfRows and another delegate after you parse data. Just add tableview.reloadData() like this

```
parse() { result in

DispatchQueue.main.async {
               print("parse")
                    if  {
                        tableview.reloadData() 
                    }
                    else {return}
                    }
                }
```

Comment: it says Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)' if I insert it does that mean my tableview isnt connected properly ?

Comment: firstly create an outlet of the tableview and then right tableView.delegate = self or create delegate of it from storyboard

Comment: I've created an outlet and the viewcontroller was already a datasource and delegate through the storyboard but the error still remains

Comment: I think you are using old delegate. or what is the outlet of tableview you have given?

Comment: tableview and tableView are two different things, so firstly check that. So define the tableview outlet as tableview and then use tableview.reloadData()

Comment: okay renamed the outlet and the reload is working now. Im getting some error about calling a background thread but that maybe caused by other parts of my code. So thank you for your help so far. :D

Comment: use dispatch statement for that. Check the above edit

Comment: yeah got that already its working now. thank you for your help and patience! :)

Answer (score 0):

The order is correct. The single steps are

- First `"viewDidLoad"` is printed because `parse` works asynchronously.
- Then the framework calls `tableView.reloadData()` once implicitly. This causes to print `"numberOfRows"` (sometimes more than once). At this moment the data source array is empty so `cellForRowAt` is not going to be called.
- Meanwhile `parse` has finished its job, the closure is executed and `"parse"` is printed.
- Finally the explicit `tableView.reloadData()` is executed and updates the UI with the received data. If `parse` is performed on a background thread you have to reload the table view on the main thread

  ```
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.tableview.reloadData() 
  }
  ```